# CGPath not visible

Tags: iphone, cgcontext

I want to create a CGPath to look like a trail in an overview perspective. I have the following code in a UIView subclass. I know I am entering the methods through NSLogs. The CGPath doesn't appear on the screen.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{
  CGMutablePathRef p = CGPathCreateMutable();
  CGPathMoveToPoint( p, NULL , 150 , 150 );
  CGPathMoveToPoint( p, NULL , 300 , 300 );
  CGPathMoveToPoint( p, NULL , 100 , 150 ) ;
  CGPathMoveToPoint( p, NULL , 150 , 150 );
  CGPathAddLineToPoint( p, NULL , 300 , 300 );
  CGPathAddLineToPoint( p, NULL , 100 , 150 ) ;
  CGPathAddLineToPoint( p, NULL , 150 , 150 );

  CGPathCloseSubpath( p ) ;

  CGContextRef context=UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(); 
  CGContextBeginPath(context);
  CGContextAddPath ( context, p ) ;
  CGContextSaveGState(context); 

  CGColorRef redColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:12.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.0].CGColor;
  CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, redColor);
  CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 20.0);
  CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);

  CGContextStrokePath(context);
  CGContextFillPath ( context ) ;

  CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFill);
  CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}
```

Nothing shows up 
In advance thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The frameworks ensure that in `-drawRect:` there is already an appropriate graphics context set up for you and pointed at the display device.  You only need `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext()`/`UIGraphicsEndImageContext()` if you are setting up to render someplace else, such as to an image.

Delete those calls and things will behave a lot better.  Right now you are rendering to an off-screen buffer, not to the view itself.

Edit: You should, however, add a pair of `CGContextSaveGState()` / `CGContextRestoreGState()` calls around your code, however.  This will ensure you don't contaminate the graphics context for other graphics code if your `-drawRect:` is used in certain ways.

Edit 2: Alright, I see that you have resolved the issue after your last response, but for the benefit of archives, I am going to point out that you never call `-drawRect:` directly (except in some obscure cases that don't apply here).  Since you had called it directly, no graphics context had been set up, hence the crash.  The proper way to trigger redraw is to send the view `-setNeedsDisplay`; this will cause the frameworks to setup a graphics context and invoke `-drawRect:` for you at the appropriate time in the run loop.

Comment: I updated my code buy still nothing show up. I have a ViewController if it means anything. And I get an error <Error>: CGContextBeginPath: invalid context 0x0

Comment: What? I don't see how context could be nil. Are you calling -drawRect: yourself by any chance?

Comment: I figured it out. Thank you for all your help it is very much appreciated.

Comment: Great.  Please review my edit to make sure that this was the ultimate issue you found.  (You can also accept my answer if it proved decisive in your debugging. ;-)

Comment: How can I create the CGPath etc outside the drawRect method.

I assume that I have to create a context to render to an image. But what would the method look like?

Comment: You can create a CGPath outside -drawRect: just fine.  If you want to actually render it, use UIGraphicsBeginImageContext() as you initially did to setup a context, and UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() to get the image.  See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html

Answer (score 1):

If on iOS, switch to bezier paths using UIBezierPath. Sure-fire to work.
Also, I've noticed, each of your moveToPoints are in a single row, when they should have one addLineToPoint right after them, like so:

> CGPathMoveToPoint(p, NULL, 150, 150);
> CGPathAddLineToPoint( p, NULL, 300, 300);
>
> CGPathMoveToPoint(p, NULL, 300, 300 ;
> CGPathAddLineToPoint(p, NULL, 100, 150);
>
> CGPathMoveToPoint(p, NULL, 100, 150);
> CGPathAddLineToPoint(p, NULL, 100, 150);
>
> CGPathMoveToPoint(p, NULL, 150, 150);
> CGPathAddLineToPoint(p, NULL, 150, 150);

But you'll want to switch to UIBezierPaths anyway once you see how easy they are.

Comment: While I don't dispute that UIBezierPath is a great shortcut when usable (and assuming you aren't writing cross-platform drawing code), the UIBezierPath would similarly have failed for Steven for the bigger reason I just outlined in my own response.  Good catch on the move-to-point, though... that would lead to broken, but not missing, drawing.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean there. Thanks for pointing that out! I learn something new everyday here :D